# How can I pass an Intent to layout which contains ListView? (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, listview, android-intent, android-studio

I am trying to pass an Intent from my mainScreen Activity class to a new android class with a layout that contains a ListView ..

MainActivityScreen Code :
(TimePassed is in the format of 'HH:MM:SS')

```
public void MoveToShiftsPage(View view) {

    Intent shiftsIntent=new Intent(this,Shifts.class);
    shiftsIntent.putExtra("time",TimePassed);

    startActivity(shiftsIntent);

}
```

"MoveToShiftsPage" in the MainActivity.xml file :

```
    <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:src="@mipmap/payment"
            android:id="@+id/shiftbtn"
            android:onClick="MoveToShiftsPage"

            />
```

Shifts.xml File( the layout which contains the ListView and the Intent sent to it)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" tools:context=".MainScreen"
>

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:id="@+id/MyListView"
    android:clickable="true"
    style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.ListView.DropDown">

</ListView>
   />
```

and the Shift.class which gets the Intent and it's supposed to represent the ListView with the time that passed :

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.app.ListFragment;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by user on 19/09/2015.
 */
public class Shifts extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

      setContentView(R.layout.shifts);
Intent MyIntent=getIntent();
        String TimePassed=MyIntent.getStringExtra("time");
        String [] timepass=TimePassed.split(":");
        ListAdapter theAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>    
    (this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1,timepass);
        ListView thelist=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.MyListView);
        thelist.setAdapter(theAdapter);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately whenever I click on the image button which is supposed to be sent to the shift activity class and represents the layout with the ListView  the app crashes ..
what should I do ?

Comment: "the app crashes .. what should I do ?" -- use LogCat to examine the Java stack trace associated with your crash: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Comment: can you post your logCat error

Answer (score 0):

try this one hopefully it works

Intent MyIntent=this.getIntent();